# complexity of a constraint satisfaction promise problem

Tags: np-hardness, csp, promise-problems

(This is the "upper end" of [my question from over 10 months ago](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/51828/12859) on cs.stackexchange.

That question and the "lower end" I asked [here over 8 months ago](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/33950/6973),

which I also have a bounty on, are both unanswered.

[These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5nnt.png)  are [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwVC9.png) of what this post should look like, in case it's not rendering correctly.)

**beginning of Motivation Section:**

I started wondering whether-or-not [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem)

can be extended to [promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem)-constraints ​ As part of that, I looked for

*the simplest* promise-constraint for which the answer is not trivial:

To avoid Schaefer's  theorem already applying, there must be at least one input tuple for which the promise fails. ​ For the same reason as that theorem, all-true and all-false must give NO, and there must be more than one input that gives YES. ​ In particular, there must be more than four possible inputs, so the promise-constraint must be over at least 3 variables. ​ To get a *simple* one, suppose it is over exactly 3 variables and is symmetric, i.e., depends only on *how many* of its inputs are true, not which ones those are. ​ In that case, either 2-true gives YES and the promise fails for 1-true, of 1-true gives YES and the promise fails for 2-true. ​ By just flipping each variable, those are equivalently hard, so to provide a shorter formal statement and "nicer" name, I will use the latter, i.e., exactly-1-true gives YES and the promise fails for 2-true.

**end of motivation section**

> **My Question**
>
> Let “positive 1.2-in-3-SAT" be the [promise problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem)
>
> Inputs have the syntax of [3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability) without negations
>
> must output YES if: ​ ​ ​ the input is [1-in-3-satisfiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability)
>
> must output ​ NO if: ​ ​ ​ the input is *not* [NAE-satisfiable](http://blog.geomblog.org/2008/03/joys-of-nae-sat.html)
>
> .
> What is that problem's complexity?
>
> You get to choose whether-or-not a variable can occur twice in a single promise-constraint.

(A variable occurring 3 times in a single promise-constraint

would automatically make it a must-output-NO instance.)

Obviously, the identity function is a reduction from the promise problem to positive 1-in-3-SAT

and to positive NAE-SAT, so [GC](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:G#gc)(O(m),[coNLOGTIME](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Eimmerman/pub/cspJCSS.pdf#page=4)) can solve the promise problem.

However, there is a seemingly-trivial observation which leads to a

combinatorial obstruction to "simple" NP-hardness proofs for positive 1.2-in-3-SAT:

For any set of variables that meets at least one promise-constraint more than once,

there is no 1-in-3-satisfying assignment in which those variables are all true.

Conversely, for any set of variables that meets each promise-constraint at most once, for any

1-in-3-satisfying assignment, possibly-modifying it to make all of the variables in that set true gives a NAE-satisfying assignment. ​ In particular, the disjunction of two 1-in-3-satisfying assignments

is always a NAE-satisfying assignment. ​ To elaborate on the consequences of that,

assume positive 1.2-in-3-SAT has a [gadget](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/9180/6973) that implements a promise-constraint C, such that

the gadget "represents and interprets C's variables in the same way as each other", i.e.,

(correspondence:) ​ each of C's input variables corresponds

to an ordered subset of the variables in the gadget

and
(similar way:) ​ those subsets are of the same size as each other; I'll call that size j

and
(represents:) ​ there is a function ​ $forward$ ​ from the domain of C's variables

to {False,True}<sup>$\hspace{.02 in}$j</sup> such that for each YES input to C, there is a 1-in-3-satisfying

assignment to the gadget such that for each of C's input variables x,

[the assignment to the gadget-variables x corresponds to in their order] is $forward$(x)

and
(interprets:) ​ there is a function ​ $backward$ ​ from {False,True}<sup>$\hspace{.02 in}$j</sup> to the domain to C's variables such that for each NAE-satisfying assignment to the gadget, [setting each of C's input variables x to

[$backward$ ​ of [x's corresponding gadget-variables in their order]]] does *not* cause C to give NO

. ​ ​ ​ In that case, for each of C's variables x and y, if C has a YES input such that (x,y)=(a,b) and

a YES input such that (x,y)=(b,a), then it has an input such that x=y but it does not give NO.

In particular, such gadgets cannot even implement [promise-coloring](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1083&context=cis_papers).

Also, the complement of a 1-in-3-satisfying assignment is always a NAE-satisfying assignment, which imposes weaker restrictions on the kinds of gadgets that positive 1.2-in-3-SAT might have.

> Is anything else known about the possibility of positive 1.2-in-3-SAT being
>
> "CSP-complete" like [3-SAT and positive 1-in-3-SAT and positive NAE-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability),
>
> i.e., having gadgets for every [possible constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem#Formal_definition)?
>
> In particular, with $m$ being the number of promise-constraints, showing that the promise problem is in ​ [promise](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#promisebqp)co[QIP[2]](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#qip2)T[IME](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#ntime)$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big(\hspace{-0.04 in}$2<sup>[o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(m)</sup>$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)\hspace{-0.04 in}\big/\hspace{-0.04 in}$[q](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#qmaqpoly)2<sup>[o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(m)</sup> ​ for infinitely many $m$ would more-than suffice.

Comment: Let's say that we are given a Boolean expression F in 3-CNF, where none of the literals are negated. Ok... We are promised that there is always a solution, since you want it to be YES = 1-in-3-SAT and NO = NAE-SAT. However, what you are missing is that F could be both 1-in-3-SAT and NAE-SAT at the same time. For example, it can have a satisfying truth assignment, where exactly 1 literal is satisfied so it is 1-in-3-SAT, but this also puts it in NAE-SAT since the literals of all of the clauses are not all True or False.

Comment: How about YES = 1 in 3 SAT, NO = 2 in 3 SAT. ? :-)

Comment: "this also puts it in NAE-SAT", meaning it's _not not_ NAE-satisfiable, so I don't see the problem with what I wrote. ​ ​

Comment: Yes. I just saw that you want ~NAE-SAT... So you want all of the literals of each clause to be either all True or all False. Correct?

Comment: All True part is not doable unless you have negations... And the same variable twice with opposite polarity within the same clause.

Comment: So the promise is, YES = 1 in 3 SAT, satisfiability, NO = All literals of each and every clause equals false, unsatisfiability . Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's NO = for all assignments, at least one triple is such that its variables all have the same value as each other. ​ ​

Comment: Okay. I got confused. I thought about total number of satisfying truth assignments...

Comment: I do not see this being a subset of NP or #P. It needs to be a subset of the complexity class X, where machine X not only solves for satisfiability but it also checks an additional constraint that the satisfiability is of certain type, 1in3-SAT or ~NAE-SAT.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the question whether Shaefer’s dichotomy theorem (or more generally, the Feder–Vardi conjecture, recently proved by [Bulatov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03021) and [Zhuk](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01914)) can be generalized to promise problems: the complexity of promise CSPs is currently a hot research topic. It is still very much open if there is such a dichotomy even for Boolean PCSPs. However, partial results are known, in particular Brakensiek and Guruswami [1] prove dichotomy for symmetric Boolean PCSPs that allow for negation of variables.

In particular, the “1.2-in-3-SAT” problem is solvable in polynomial time—even if we allow negative literals—by Theorem 2.6 in [1], as it has the alternating threshold functions $x_1-x_2+x_3-\dots-x_{L-1}+x_L$ as weak polymorphisms. The paper gives in fact two different algorithms.

**Algorithm 1:**

Let $C$ be the input $3$-CNF. Identifying negative literals $\overline{x_i}$ with $1-x_i$, let $L_C$ be the linear system consisting of the equations
$$u+v+w=1$$
for each clause $\{u,v,w\}\in C$. Using e.g. a polynomial-time algorithm for Hermite normal forms, compute an integer solution $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of $L_C$ if it exists.

If there is no solution, then $C$ is not 1-in-3 satisfiable.

If there is a solution, then
$$x'_i=\begin{cases}1&x_i\ge1,\\0&x_i\le0\end{cases}$$
defines a NAE-satisfying assignment of $C$.

(Both claims are straightforward to verify.)

**Algorithm 2:**

Let $P_C$ be the linear program consisting of the linear system $L_C$ above and the bounds
$$0\le x_i\le1$$
for all variables $x_i$.

If for some $i$, neither $P_C\cup\{x_i=0\}$ nor $P_C\cup\{x_i=1\}$ is feasible, then $C$ is not 1-in-3-satisfiable. (This is obvious.)

Otherwise, $C$ is NAE-satisfiable. (This requires some work to prove, see §3.2 in [1].)

The corresponding promise search problem is solvable in polynomial time as well: given a 1-in-3-satisfiable $3$-CNF $C$, compute a NAE-satisfying assignment to $C$. Algorithm 1 does just that; the paper mentions that Algorithm 2 can also be extended to yield this.

**Reference:**

[1] Joshua Brakensiek and Venkatesan Guruswami, *Promise Constraint Satisfaction: Algebraic Structure and a Symmetric Boolean Dichotomy*, [arXiv:1704.01937](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01937) [cs.CC].